# New language on top of PHP?

Tags: php, programming-languages, language-design

I'm a PHP developer. I like PHP! It is a really good language if you know how to use it, but I know it allows [very bad design](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-crawling-horrors-of-PHP) sometimes.

It reminds me of JavaScript which has good parts and bad parts. One particular project, CoffeeScript, tries to focus only on the good parts, forcing you to write good code.

I was thinking if something similar could be done with PHP... A new syntax that would be compiled only to good PHP code taking advatage of all the new and exciting stuff we can get with PHP 5.3.

So, getting ahead of some people, I'll ask: **Why create a new language on top of PHP if you can just use Ruby or Python or something else?**

- PHP is easy to deploy anywhere
- The language itself has a lot of good features and ideas
- There are lots of good libraries written in PHP
- ...

So, my real questions here are...

- Is this a stupid idea? Why would it be? Do you think CoffeeScript is stupid?
- How do someone starts to create a new language on top of another? I know nothing about this, but I would like to learn. Where to start?

Comment: Interesting. I've been dreaming of something like this (or rather, a "clean" PHP fork) for a long time. This would need major community traction to get somewhere, but would be a worthy project...

Comment: Not competing, but related: The Suhosin patch http://www.hardened-php.net/

Comment: If you ask me, you should absolutely do this (I also consider CoffeeScript very neat) and use the oppoturnity to make a language that is designed at all (not to mention properly) - but then again, I use Python ;) See numerous questions on SO for information on making a language and be warned that this can be a large task.

Comment: You might want to have a look into [`phpreboot`](http://code.google.com/p/phpreboot/) which is a PHP-Javascript cross for the JVM. And also [`pihipi`](http://code.google.com/p/pihipi/) which is a metacompiler generating runnable php from a PHP+Python-like hybrid language.

Comment: @mario: pihipi definitely looks interesting. But it also shows that if a language on top of PHP is going to be created, then it should be properly designed. Only one single design decision (like disallowing dynamic includes) makes the project completely and utterly unusable.

Comment: @nikic: Don't know about that, not tested much. I would assume if it disallows that it's due to single-pass parser constraints. Yet a `php::include($var)` should be possible.

Comment: I've started do design a syntax... Please, take a look: https://gist.github.com/781189

Comment: Does Eber live in a parallel universe where PHP is not one of the worst languages ever created or do I miss the sarcasm here?

Comment: I think you owe it to the community to accept this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19094945/193892  I get no rep from it, just want to spread the word about Snowscript because it needs help. Fully functional though!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea is definitely not stupid, especially if executed well.

I like coffeescript a lot, but it has it's approach has downsides as well. Debugging a coffeescript script still requires you read the generated Javascript code, which can be tedious, since you haven't written it actually yourself.

I've understood that Jeremy Ashkenas, the creator of coffeescript has started to work on coffeescript after reading ["Create your own freaking awesome programming language" by Marc-André Cournoyer](http://createyourproglang.com/index2.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the book recomendation :)

Comment: But to be fair, Coffeescript's JS output is very readable and mostly pretty close to the input.

Answer (score 10):

The reason CoffeScript is a good idea is that if developers want to run code in a client browser they **have** to use javascript; so the only way to program in a different language is to allow that language to be convertible to javascript.

I'm not sure the same really applies to server side programming. If you've got issues with PHP and want to use a new language there is no real advantage to having that language generate PHP.

On the other hand, a language that was very similar to PHP, but fixed some of the flaws would be a great idea.

Comment: Yes there is an advantage in compiling to PHP (OP also said that!): Just like JS is ubiquitous on the client side, PHP is ubiquitous on the server side -> easy to host.

Answer (score 4):

It is here now. A [new language](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript) which is to PHP what CoffeeScript is to Javascript. (I.e., awesome.)

***[SNOWSCRIPT](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript)***

Snowscript code looks like this:

---

```
fn how_big_is_it(number)
    if number < 100
        <- "small"
    else
        <- "big"
```

PHP output looks like this:

---

```
function how_big_is_it($number) {
    if ($number < 100) {
        return "small";
    } else {
        return "big";
    }
}
```

All it needs now, is [you](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript/issues?state=open).

Answer (score 3):

Heh, great idea. My thoughts, some contradictory...

There are precedents for civilizing bad languages by putting syntax preprocessors in front of them.

- In the early days of Unix, Fortran was popular and about the only portable language because most machines had no C compiler. But the vanilla Fortran of the day didn't even have block structured *if-then-else*, just a goofy single-statement *if* or an *if-goto*.  So, the ***[Ratfor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratfor)*** language was implemented as a preprocessor for Fortran-66.
- I believe there were (are?) Cobol preprocessors that presumably dealt with the verbosity and limitations of early Cobol dialects.
- To this day Unix-derived systems ship with a macro processor called m4.
- Several CSS preprocessors are available today, most notably ***[Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)*** and ***[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)***.

But...

- *Just let it die, and the sooner the better*
- The problem isn't really in the syntax.
- I don't see much of a JavaScript-PHP parallel. JavaScript is a great language. It's kind of the opposite of PHP.
- I'm not sure why you say that PHP is a great language. It's one of the worst. Every decent feature is a patch or repatch in a recent version.
- As you noted, there is a fixed-up version of PHP already: it's called ***Ruby*** and, as a language, it's near-perfect. There is another fixed-up version called ***Python***. The world would be better off in the long run if we support the better systems.

Comment: The thing about Ruby is that it can be a pain to get up and running with, especially if you go with (the quite common) Rails.  Once you're running, it's great...but it takes effort to get there.  PHP, on the other hand, is pretty much always ready to go -- stick an index.php in your doc root, and it just about always runs without incident.  (Probably cause everyone uses PHP, requiring that anyone be able to set it up.)  *That* is what i like about PHP.  The language itself is hideous, but when you wanna see something now, JFW > perfect.  I'm not familiar enough with Python to comment.

Comment: Not seeing much there about how to run under an existing Apache server (by far the most common setup on Linux boxes i've encountered).  That's the issue.  I can't just replace Apache, as it could be serving a dozen other (PHP and other non-Ruby) sites -- but having that :3000 (for Mongrel? or is that WEBrick?) or :4567 (for Sinatra) or whatever in the URLs just feels wrong to me.  Why don't they tell people how to set up Apache to pass the stuff through to the Ruby server?  That should be a standard part of the documentation IMO.

Comment: WEBrick is mainly for personal debugging, although I suppose a small site could run it. The normal setup is Apache (or nginx) + Passenger, or perhaps Mongrel. Any admin or web engineer should be able to set that up. If you just want to run it for development, both Rails and Sinatra will automatically run a server for you. Are you talking about setting up a real online server or just setting up for debugging?

Comment: I'm talking about setting up a real server.  I've managed to set up a piddly little dev site with Rails; it's easy enough, cause as you've mentioned, Rails will start a web server for you.  But setting up Apache to talk to Mongrel or whatever...it's probably not that hard, but it's also not documented very well.

Comment: The similarity is not super strong, but there are a million cheap web hosts where you can run only PHP scripts. And almost all the *other* web hosts can *also* run PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If it would be to PHP what something like sass is to CSS, I'd be interested. But what would exactly would you want to add? Or would you just want to weed out the bad?

And what would you consider to be the bad?

Comment: The link I posted on the question above has some of the bad design choices that can be done with PHP. The primary objective would be to weed out the bad things, but also implement better syntax for some things like... Allow basic data to be accessed as an object and perform things like: $string = 'Foo|Bar'; $array = $string.split('|');

Comment: Oh yes, I agree with a lot of the things in that list.... agree with getting rid of them, that is. This would be a noble task indeed... I will be following this with great interest.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a PHP syntax transformer would probably be a neat project.

However, don't forget that PHP's standard library is a huge mess. Cleaning that up, would be a far bigger task.

Answer (score 2):

The more I am thinking about this, the more irrealistic it sounds. The reason is simple: There actually ***are*** such language proprocessors already. Two of them (though not using PHP as implementation, only as compilation target) can be found [here](http://www.simpleanswer.us/answer/best-way-to-implement-a-meta-language-compiling-down-to-php). But simply nobody uses them.

Yes, if the compiler itself were written in PHP, probably more people would use it. But I really can't see a way how to get this popular enough to be worth the work.

Another big problem is, that people mostly are used to their awesome code-highlighting, code-completing, code-inspecting IDE. Without getting IDE support probably merely anybody will use it (and IDE support can only be obtained by having many people use it...)

Thoughts?

Comment: Random thoughts: Existing languages targeting PHP require a compile step, which breaks the normal PHP development cycle. JS is perhaps more attractive as a target language because [source maps](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/sourcemaps) are widely supported. PHP (for various reasons) is a horrible language for writing compilers - it's generally simpler/easier in JS. Completion/inspections aren't PHP-specific problems - any new language faces that; IDE support for PHP itself isn't great. And [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) uses an inspiring approach, being able to transpile in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

I can see writing compilers to JavaScript (because the web imposes it upon us), but this sounds like a waste of time.

[Haxe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haxe) already does this, although it's not specifically targeted at PHP (linked to the Wikipedia article instead of their website because I'm afraid I'm going to get exploited if I visit the real site...)

> PHP is easy to deploy anywhere

...as are its vulnerabilities.

> I know it allows very bad design sometimes.

That's a bit of an understatement, it doesn't even have a module system, has no encapsulation, and has tons of silly things such as [dynamic name resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789195/dynamic-name-resolution).

PHP is slow enough as it is, do you really want something an order of a magnitude slower?

Java is much more easy to deploy anyways, and lets you drop down to the bytecode level if you want. Java also gives you access to moderately sane libraries.

Comment: Try finding good, free Java hosting. Contrast with how easy it is to find PHP hosting.

Comment: @delnan: free hosts are usually insecure and just garbage in general.

Comment: @Longpoke: Can't judge the quality. The main advantage (for a language) is a different one: PHP runs half of the web partly because it's very easy to get started with; and exploiting the widespread use of the parent language can give a new language a significant headstart (also see C++). Despite being a horrible programming language.

Comment: @delnan: just because it's easy to get started with doesn't mean it's worth anything. Also a language on top of PHP will probably kill any free host's time slices.

Comment: @Longpoke: (1) No, of course not. But even the greatest language doesn't go anywhere if nobody uses it. (2) Depends. Not only on the new language, but also on the implementation and the program that's run. OP's ideas don't sound like he's trying to build a PHP interpreter for the next Haskell but a translator for a language on about the same level on abstraction.

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, if it's just some syntactic sugar (like adding operator overloading) or maybe even building simple objects to represent language constructs at runtime, it might not be so bad.

Comment: Hosting in 2016 is no longer any real concern, and no longer a good argument for choosing PHP - anyone can afford cheap hosting now, with root access to deploy anything, even compiled C binaries if you fancy. Arguing availability in favor of PHP now, five years later, is like beating a dead horse.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have thought about already often. PHP just is messy at some points.

Actually, I already have a project [PrePHP](https://github.com/nikic/prephp) focusing on providing PHP 5.3 functionality to PHP 5.2. But it adds some minor language features, like `func()[0]`. I haven't developed this project for some time and it definitely isn't "clean", but it shows, that what you want is possible and actually even not that complicated.

If you are serious about this, I am perfectly willing to collaborate with you.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad to know :) Maybe I'll creat a manifest or something!

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting idea and if it come to life i think that i wan't to be involved in :)

For start You may check and read this position [http://www.amazon.com/Masterminds-Programming-Conversations-Creators-Languages/dp/0596515170](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515170) (iam reading it now). It makes clear how really complicated is to maintain own language.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that PHP definitely could do with some improvement, right now it allows for too much fooling around.

Some things I'd like to see

- Static Typing
- Required indentation
- Proper use of objects (using arrays as objects is just stupid)

Then again, maybe I should just drop PHP and start working with Ruby or Python.

Comment: Haskell satisfies all of those points (indentation is significant, but not always required - but almost always used) (uses algebraic data types instead of "objects", but they are actually used somewhat properly, unlike how PHP works. Python is close but no static typing, and has "objects" (although they are very similar to associative arrays in PHP, they are just a dict of functions optionally bound to a `self`)... seriously, just skip Python/Ruby and go to Haskell, you'll be glad you saved time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm like 8 years too late, but I'll answer anyways for anyone else who stumbles upon this.

[Hack](https://hacklang.org) is a language developed by Facebook to deal with some of the issues of PHP, since Facebook had a large PHP codebase. Hack adds some nice features on top of PHP such as gradual typing (what TypeScript has) and generics, among other features, and gets rid of some of the more dangerous PHP features. Hack was at one point a superset of PHP, but is no longer completely compatible after removing some of the worse PHP features.

This is slightly different from what you were asking, since at this point Hack has its own interpreter, written by Facebook, but this started out as "better language that compiles to PHP", so I thought it was worth mentioning here.