# Dynamic name resolution

Tags: language-design

Howcome some languages like PHP and Python use [dynamic name resolution](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dynamic_name_resolution#Static_versus_dynamic)?

The only time I've ever thought of using it is to do something like this Python code, to save me from having to explicitly parameters to `format`:

```
"{a} {b} {c} {d}".format(**locals())
```

but it doesn't really take much work to just be explicit (and is a bit less error-prone):

```
"{a} {b} {c} {d}".format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

And for setting/getting locals in the same scope, I don't see why anyone would ever use that instead of a map.

Without dynamic name resolution, typos are caught, and you can automatically rename variables without breaking your program (unless something can still read the names of the variables). With dynamic name resolution, you get something that saves you from typing a line? Am I missing something?

Python documentation says they might remove it in the future. Is it more of a historical thing? What's an actual good use case for dynamic name resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Most dynamically typed languages simply don't have a choice. For an expression like `x.y` you can't look up `y` statically, since what fields are available depends on the type of `x` which is only available at runtime.

There are ways around this (such as type inference or JIT), but since the base language *has* to have dynamic name lookup, most such languages make it into a feature (see e.g. the power of Lua tables).

Comment: Your example seems more dynamic typing than name resolution, no?

Comment: You are talking about the set of attributes on an object being determined dynamically. The "dynamic name resolution" I'm talking about here is the local/global scope not being determined statically. eg `f() { return x + 1 }` will fail at runtime even though it's obvious that x is not in scope anywhere (assuming f is a top level function and not part of some object). I guess in the object case if the language allows attributes to implicitly be referred to without `this`/`self`, etc, and the methods of an object can change at runtime, then you'd need dynamic scope resolution.

Comment: Longpoke: sorry, only saw this just now. In that case, there is no valid reason assuming the language is meant to be lexically scoped. The only reason I can think of it that it was like that in an early implementation for convenience (especially if it had unintended dynamic scoping features), and they've been lazy about fixing it for fear of breaking some corner cases.