# Is there anything like CoffeeScript for PHP?

Tags: php, programming-languages

PHP interpreters are very common, but the PHP syntax & libraries are inconsistent & cumbersome (IMO, of course). I think a language that compiles into PHP but provides higher level level features (like, modules, mixins, list comprehensions, etc...) and easier syntax (like optional semicolons, implied returns, no dollar sign for variables, optional brackets and braces, etc...) would be valuable. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: How about just using another language? AFAIK Coffeescript is used because there is no viable alternative client scripting language to javascript. If you *must* have PHP, try Smarty perhaps (compiles into PHP, extendable, create your own syntax for the most part).

Comment: possible duplicate of [New language on top of PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700276/new-language-on-top-of-php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer is "no." CoffeeScript rose to popularity because of a unique confluence of factors. For one, as Wesley points out, JavaScript has a monopoly on the browser platform, while PHP only has a monopoly on `.php` files. On your own servers, if you don't like PHP, you can just use Ruby, Python, Perl, or any of the myriad JVM or .NET languages.

Another factor is that JavaScript's design was something of an accident. Its creator, Brendan Eich, was told to "make it look like Java"; but semantically, it has more in common with Lisp and Smalltalk. CoffeeScript arguably provides a syntax that's a better fit with JavaScript's inner workings.

JavaScript's own syntactic evolution is severely hindered by the need to maintain compatibility with older browsers. PHP suffers no such limitations, as anyone who's transitioned their code from PHP4 to PHP5 can attest. If you want to make JavaScript a better language, you need a precompiler. If you want to make PHP a better language, post a feature request for PHP6. (**Edit:** In my original answer, I fell for an April Fool's joke claiming that [PHP6 had been released in 2010](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2010/04/php-6-finally-released.html). Obviously I'm not a PHP guy...)

All of that said, it could be cool to have a language that's like CoffeeScript for PHP. The ongoing success of WordPress, and its use on servers that users often have little control over, attests to PHP's unique place as a deployed language. It's also difficult to use PHP with alternative markup languages like Haml. Perhaps an alternative markup language combined with a fresh PHP syntax could produce a compelling enough reason for people to precompile their PHP.

Comment: +1, but I think you should read that article about PHP6 one more time... and note the date it was posted :D

Comment: I think there is a valid case for wanting a php intermediate format - it is supported by virtually every shared hosting service available.  Node(js) and other languages don't have nearly the ubiquitous support.  I imagine Perl has similarly high availability.  If you are writing wordpress plugins for example, having an alternate syntax might be attractive.  I'd love something that got rid of that freakish -> syntax :)

Comment: I've worked on a language with ruby-ish syntax (https://github.com/gosukiwi/IcedTea) it's pretty functional and simplistic, even though it lacks some syntactic sugar a la CoffeeScript.

Comment: Mammouth is a fairly interesting project. Oh and it copies coffeescript
http://mammouth.wamalaka.com/#installation

Comment: "JavaScript's design was something of an accident" -- I think that applies to PHP as well.

Comment: Note that you can find Mammouth now at http://mammouth.boutglay.com/ or at their GitHub page at https://github.com/btwael/mammouth

Answer (score 25):

I've been researching this a lot and at the moment it seems the answer is no. I'm the author of exactly such a project called [Snowscript](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript) - it is far from complete, but the documentation is pretty good and some things do work. Would love to hear feedback of what you think about the syntax!

Comment: You just gave me a new project to follow. :D

Comment: Updated link for [Snow](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript): https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript

Comment: At the moment, the answer *IS YES*!  Don't be so modest, this thing is looking awesome.

Comment: That looks amazing. I hope that project won't disappear with the time. :)

Comment: That looks great indeed, might be able to support that somewhat!

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Drop by and help some :)

Comment: @RuneKaagaard, I have started to organize my efforts in life to not spread too thin. But what you did is really great and IMHO if the spec was locked some early adopter would dare do production code with Snowscript already.

Answer (score 16):

Browsing and surfing the web I've found http://mammouth.boutglay.com/ looks like the most similar to coffee-script language for PHP. Seems to do the job.

Answer (score 12):

If I've understood what you want correctly, then there's [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), which can target PHP, as well as Flash, JavaScript, and others.

I've only ever used it for Flash but found it very useful.

Comment: True, haXe is probably the only popular language that compiles to PHP. Of course, it's much further removed from PHP than CoffeeScript is from JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

If you like Lisps, have a look at [Pharen](http://scriptor.github.com/pharen/). I haven't needed to use it yet, but it looks pretty nice - it has **defmacro** and even transforms tail recursion into loops.

Answer (score 4):

[@gosukiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015566/gosukiwi) made [Blueberry](https://github.com/gosukiwi/Blueberry), which looks like this:

```
/* 
 I'm a multiline comment
*/

a = 1 # variable definition

# you can use JSON syntax to define associative arrays
arr = { "name": "Mike", "age": 18, "meta": { "items": [1, 2, 3] } }

if a == 1
  echo("Hello, World!")
end

for i in (0..10)
  echo(i)
end

class MyClass < MyParentClass
  @name

  def Greet
    echo("Hello! My name is " & @name)
  end
end
```

They also mentioned it in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551089/is-there-anything-like-coffeescript-for-php/6801794#comment29681858_6552074).

Comment: This is nice, used it to convert some JSON into a PHP data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no production-ready or completed coffeescript-like language/compiler for PHP.

I am the author of CoffeePHP, and is working on the compiler for the shorter syntax. it's actually another language.

https://github.com/c9s/coffeephp

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you might be aware of this, but you could simply use [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) with CoffeeScript... (unless you're specifically attached to PHP)

Comment: In retrospect I guess the nodejs connection is obvious to anyone familiar with CoffeeScript. Don't know why I gave this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This library isn't like CoffeeScript, in itself, but it's a foundation for rewriting PHP to declare and use your own syntax. I don't have any experience with it, so don't read this as an endorsement, just an observation. https://github.com/theseer/preprocessor

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at coffescript-php project which is compatible with coffescript 1.3.1 on github can be found at https://github.com/alxlit/coffeescript-php

Comment: That compiles CoffeeScript to JavaScript, written in PHP. The OP is looking for a language which compiles to PHP.