# CoffeeScript-esque language for PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anything like CoffeeScript for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551089/is-there-anything-like-coffeescript-for-php)

We've all heard of CoffeeScript but is there a language that works in a similar way but for PHP instead of JavaScript?